# Calculating neighbor-distances for all grid points in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Imagine a 3-dimensional grid in space, where each grid point has a binary value.
The values of the grid points are represented by a 3d numpy array.

For each grid point that has a value of 1, we want to know where the nearest 0-valued point is located, in 14 different directions (±x, ±y, ±z, and 8 diagonals).

That means, with a numpy array of shape (nx, ny, nz) as input, the output should be an array of shape (nx, ny, nz, 14), where each value in the last dimension of the output corresponds to distance of that point to the nearest 0-valued neighbor in one direction (but we don't need to calculate this for 0-valued grid points, so their values can be set to zero).

What is the most efficient way to calculate this in numpy?

My current approach is looping over the grid points (three nested for-loops), and for each point, first checking whether it's a 1, and if so, slicing the array 14 times to get the points in one of the directions starting from the current point, and taking the index of first 0 element as distance to nearest 0-valued neighbor in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that should work for all the non-diagonal cases.  The example is just in 1d, but should work along each axis in 3d.  This just computes the distance to the nearest `0` to the left:

```py
a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
n = len(a)
zero_index = np.arange(0, n) * (1 - a)
one_index = np.arange(0, n) * a
(one_index - np.maximum.accumulate(zero_index)) * a
# -> returns array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

The idea is that `zero_index` has the integer index wherever `a` is 0, and `one_index` has the integer index wherever `a` is 1.  `np.maximum.accumulate` does a cumulative maximum, which fills the zero values in `zero_index` with the values from the left.  The final `* a` just sets the final distance to 0 wherever these was a `0`.

This doesn't handle the case when `a[0]` is 1.  We can fix that by offsetting the `zero_index` by 1 (so it starts with 1 if `a[0]` is 0):

```py
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
n = len(a)
zero_index = np.arange(1, n+1) * (1 - a)
one_index = np.arange(0, n) * a
(one_index - np.maximum.accumulate(zero_index) + 1) * a
# -> returns array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

You can handle the opposite direction with reverse indexing.

Unfortunately I can't propose a vectorized way of doing the diagonals. Perhaps there's a way (some kind of `shape` or `roll`) that skews the diagonal to make it aligned with an axis.

Comment: Thank you, but in the second version, the return values for the first five points (the first five 1s) are not correct; there is no 0 to their left, so they should all have a return value of 0 as well. Also, I can't intuitively expand this to 3d; or you mean just do each dimension separately in 2d?

Comment: This should generalize to any dimension - you just do these operations along one axis at a time.  So for an n-dim array, you'll need to do this 2*n times - each direction in each dimension.  If there isn't an implicit 0 outside the array, then you can solve that by using the first block of code, and set any value in the result that equals `np.arange(0, n)` to 0, since any initial sequence of `1`s will generate initial indices `0, 1, 2, ...`.